# How to include OpenCV 3 in an AWS Lambda function written in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I found instructions on how to include OpenCV 3 into an AWS Lambda function written in Python but am having trouble figuring out how to do it in java.  Does anyone know the appropriate way to include OpenCV 3 (or any other non-java items) into a java based Lambda function?

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/create-deployment-pkg-zip-java.html

Comment: I'm able to build pure java code such as having multiple dependencies listed in my maven pom and including those in the deployment.  I do not see a maven dependency for OpenCV 3 that I can simply just include as a maven dependency.  I may be missing something on the page you referenced but I do not see a way to include non-java items on that page.  For example.  Their should be a way to include non-java items into your lambda function package.  For example, items such as OpenCV 3 where I can download the source from GitHub, compile the code, and then include the .so files and utilize them.

Comment: I see your point now. This is a bit over my knowledge level of Java and AWS Lambda. I found this article, which might be helpful: https://www.adamheinrich.com/blog/2012/12/how-to-load-native-jni-library-from-jar/